# How to secure communication between Self-Hosted integration runtime nodes in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have read the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#high-availability-and-scalability and tried to setup the multi-node Self-Hosted IRs in ADF. The problem is during the second node setup it asks for the TLS/SSL certificate. The documentation does not specify exactly what to do. AS per the documentation, I added the SSL certificate (that I added in First node) in Trusted Root certificates of second node, but it asks to add the certificate inside the Self-Hosted IR. Not sure how to add the certificate in the second node.
MS documentation says "Each integration runtime node must trust this certificate." What this means? Where I need to put the original certificate in second node? Do I need to create a new certificate for the another node?
I'[image]m using Azure Windows VMs for IR setup.